# pytorch lightining get named parameters for optimizer setup

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, pytorch-lightning

Using standard pytorch I was defining a custom optimizer to fine-tune a BERT model and set the weight decay using this code below

```py
no_decay = ['bias', 'LayerNorm.weight']
optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
    {'params': [p for n, p in self.model.named_parameters() if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay': 0.01},
    {'params': [p for n, p in self.model.named_parameters() if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
     'weight_decay': 0.0}
]
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=self.config['lr'], eps=self.config['adam_eps'])
```

Now I would like to use PyTorchLighting so I need to define the method `configure_optimizers():` The problem is that I cannot call the `self.model.named_parameters()` as before because the method the PyTorch offers `self.parameters()` does not return the name of the parameters. So how can I edit my code in order to achieve the same behavior on PyTorchLighting?

Comment: Have you tried `self.named_parameters()`? It should give you the parameter list along with their keys just like `self.model.named_parameters()` is.